# Bootstrap navbar drop-down doesn't toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap navbar in my website and so i have made the webpage header.html (link given below) and it works fine

http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/header.html

However when i use the same code on my home page (link below). it doesnt close after we open it.

http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/index.html

On my homepage - index.html i have written below code.

```
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#header").load("http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/header.html");
               });
        </script>

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<!-- other things-->
</body>
```

I get the error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).dropdown is not a function
>   @http://upscfever.com/upsc-fever/index.html:1:15
>   g/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29946
>   g/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to put the `load` script just before the end of the body tag, so that the `<div id="header">` gets added to the DOM before using it.
Also make sure you are not loading bootstrap js more than once in your index.html file.

Comment: done but still doesnt work. theres a bootstrap.js in header.html and one in index.html is it ok.

Comment: Hi @pranav nerurkar, you need only one bootstrap.js to be loaded, so since you already have it in header.html, you should remove the one in index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and see if it will work.